# Restrict method chaining on other method

Tags: php

Let say i have this class

```
class Test
{

   method_a(){ return $this;}

   method_b(){ return $this;}

   method_c(){ return $this;}
}

$obj = new Test();
$obj->method_a()->method_b();
$obj->method_a()->method_c();
$obj->method_b()->method_c(); //i want to disallow this
```

How can i disallow method_b() chaining with method_c()

**Edited:**

Calling $obj->method_b() and follow by $obj->method_c() also disallow because i only want method_b chaining with method_a and method_c with other method

Comment: Isn't `$obj->method_b()->method_c();` equal to `$obj->method_b(); $obj->method_c();`. Would you disallow the latter as well?

Comment: If you are okay with both methods being called in sequence, just not in a certain *style*, I can see absolutely no sense in this question. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a State Pattern and introduce State objects for each possible state in Test. When someone calls Method B, you change the state of Test internally to the StateB class and when someone calls Method C then you can raise an Exception.

See http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state

Comment: @slier you're welcome. If this (or any other answer) solves your problem, consider accepting it by ticking the green check mark to indicate so.

Answer (score 4):

there are two possibilitys i can think of. the first is to not retun `$this` from `method_b()`. that would prevent chaining `method_c()` - but everything else, too, so this doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.

the second one is kind of ugly, but might work as intended: add another private variable `$last_method` to your class and set that in every called method (to the methods name or some kind of id). that way, when calling `method_c()`, you could check if the last called method was `method_b()` - and if so, throw an exception (or whatever you'd like to do in such a case). note that this solution would also prevent from calling `method_b()` and `method_c()` consecutive on the same object without chaining - so this might not be 100% what you're looking for.